# Room causing build errors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-room

I've spent hours trying to come up with a solution. Very non-descriptive error (for me at least).

Here's the error:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:311)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:257)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1629.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassMetadata kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassMetadata$Companion.read(kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassHeader)'
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassMetadata kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassMetadata$Companion.read(kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassHeader)'
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.KotlinMetadataElement$Companion.createFor(KotlinMetadataElement.kt:125)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacTypeElement$kotlinMetadata$2.invoke(JavacTypeElement.kt:59)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacTypeElement$kotlinMetadata$2.invoke(JavacTypeElement.kt:58)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacTypeElement.getKotlinMetadata(JavacTypeElement.kt:58)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacTypeElement$superClass$2.invoke(JavacTypeElement.kt:221)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacTypeElement$superClass$2.invoke(JavacTypeElement.kt:209)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacTypeElement.getSuperClass(JavacTypeElement.kt:209)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacTypeElement.getSuperClass(JavacTypeElement.kt:46)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.DeclarationCollectorKt$collectAllMethods$1.invokeSuspend$collectAllMethodsByName(DeclarationCollector.kt:63)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.DeclarationCollectorKt$collectAllMethods$1.invokeSuspend(DeclarationCollector.kt:80)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequenceBuilderIterator.hasNext(SequenceBuilder.kt:129)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.util.MemoizedSequence$CachedIterator.hasNext(MemoizedSequence.kt:42)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:169)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:194)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor$DefaultDelegate.onPreProcess(PojoProcessor.kt:1026)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.doProcess(PojoProcessor.kt:132)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.access$doProcess(PojoProcessor.kt:57)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor$process$1.invoke(PojoProcessor.kt:113)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor$process$1.invoke(PojoProcessor.kt:110)
    at androidx.room.processor.cache.Cache$Bucket.get(Cache.kt:53)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.process(PojoProcessor.kt:110)
    at androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor.doProcess(TableEntityProcessor.kt:94)
    at androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor.access$doProcess(TableEntityProcessor.kt:45)
    at androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor$process$1.invoke(TableEntityProcessor.kt:54)
    at androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor$process$1.invoke(TableEntityProcessor.kt:53)
    at androidx.room.processor.cache.Cache$Bucket.get(Cache.kt:53)
    at androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor.process(TableEntityProcessor.kt:53)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.processEntities(DatabaseProcessor.kt:464)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:71)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:62)
    at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep$process$databases$1$1.invoke(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:67)
    at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep$process$databases$1$1.invoke(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:63)
    at androidx.room.processor.Context.collectLogs(Context.kt:167)
    at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep.process(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:63)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.CommonProcessorDelegate.processRound(XBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:123)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacBasicAnnotationProcessor.process(JavacBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
```

It has something to do with room. If I remove all room-related code from my project and remove the room dependencies from build.gradle, the error goes away.

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'asimcodes.mvvmcaching'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "asimcodes.mvvmcaching"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        buildConfigField("String", "NEWS_API_ACCESS_KEY", news_api_access_key)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Default
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$ktxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.0"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    /*implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"*/

    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltAndroidXVersion"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"

    // Retrofit + GSON
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"

    // Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"

    // Paging 3
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$pagingVersion"

    // Swipe Refresh Layout
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

Here's the project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.8.20'
        navigationVersion = '2.5.3'
        hiltVersion = '2.46'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation.safeargs:androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.plugin:$navigationVersion")
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hiltVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    appCompatVersion = '1.6.1'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.1.4'
    materialVersion = '1.9.0'
    glideVersion = '4.13.2'
    hiltAndroidXVersion = '1.0.0'
    ktxVersion = '1.10.1'
    pagingVersion = '3.1.1'
    retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
    navigationVersion = '2.5.3'
    roomVersion = '2.5.1'
}
```

Do I have something missing here?

Comment: I had the same issue with my nexus notes on Google Play. I found out that it was a Kapt version issue with java target 17. So I had to change from java 17 to 18 and it started working again.. my note app is based off room but trying to move everything away from room because it's starting to be a pain

Comment: @CampNerd Tried changing to JAVA 18. Didn't work. Build still fails with the same error.

Comment: I will look at my room Database on My Nexus Notes and see what I have on it. I fought for three days until I got it sorted out. Mine was because I used findview instead of binding and then when I changed everything it started saying kapt version issues and I finally got it fixed so let me check my notes app I have to push an update to Google play today anyway so I will take a look

Comment: Also I am wanting to move from room because the last 3 months it has been a head ache. So my Google Play App Nexus Notes uses room but I think I am gonna implement Firebase instead. I have had room for a year. And it was great until Google started changing stuff again

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked was to replace KAPT with KSP for Room stuff. Once I did that, the above mentioned issue vanished.

Comment: can't do that unfortunately databinding requires kapt and it is not available in ksp